# How to wire a Button in a UITableViewCell with its action method

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

How can I connect a Button in a UITableViewCell with its action method in the UITableViewCell in xcode.

Crtl-Draging from the button to the source doesn´t work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a subclass of UITableViewCell. Then you can hook up your button to an action in your sublass. Connect your button to your own subclass instead of the file's owner.

Comment: Thanks, I created a subclass of UITableViewCell. How do I connect the button to this subclass? If I click in the background my UITableviewCell and ctrl-drag to the button I can wire an outlet, but no action

Comment: Ctrl-Drag form your custom cell object to your button to connect it. For an action: create the IBAction in your .h file. And connect by Ctrl-drag from your button to your custom cell.

Comment: thanks, I had to write the action method manually, than ctrl-drag worked!

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with custom cells, note that your "source" is now not the "Files Owner" but rather the "UITableViewCell" object. Hope this does the trick, if not - something is wired wrong in your code / XIB

Answer (score 0):

Do it programmatically. It is the simplest believe me. Every tableViewCell has got a contentView. So all you do is for your specific row in section in -tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
UIButton* cellButton= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect]; // Cane be custom as well
[cellButton addTarget:addTarget:self action:@selector(handleCellButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
// Further changes such as text color whatever ...

[cell.contentView addSubView:cellButton];
```

//add a handler method for the button

```
-(void)handleCellButton:(id)sender{}
```